# How to use INSERT INTO statement for a table having one to many relation

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to create a log table that will log every login attempt.

I get this error:

> You cannot add or change a record because a related record is
>   required in table 'MyUser'.

`MyUser.Username` is primary key and `UserLog.username` is foreign key.

[image]

Code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Userlog(username,lTime) VALUES (@1,@2)"; 

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = user;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();

try
{
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
     throw;
}
```

Comment: provide your database structure for us to help you

Comment: _a related record is required in table 'MyUser'_ means that if you want to insert that record with that username you need to have a record with the same username in the table MyUser. Simple as that.

Comment: @davejal - how does the database structure help? He obviously has a **MyUser** table with a **username** key.

Comment: @HannoverFist as already stated by Steve, that was were I was going with my question

Comment: Thumbs up. It was giving me error because there was no related record in MyUser table

Answer (score 1):

As written by Steve:

Before `INSERT INTO Userlog`, check that the username exists in `MyUser`. If not, insert there first.

Or in your use case, that was probably someone who mistyped their username. You should log that separately, or not at all.